# Uploading log file from client app to Amazon S3 is safe?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, logging

My application runs on the client PC. It produces log files including error reports and user's action.

To collect and analyze log files, I try to upload log files to Amazon S3 from the client PC.
But is it safe? My app has no authentication so that users can upload unlimited number of files. I am concerned with maricious user upload a fake error report and huge file. I'd like s3 bucket not to exceed free quota. Is there any best practice for this task?

Comment: What do you mean by "is it safe"? Are you saying that people might provide files with a virus, or are you saying that the files need to be kept confidential? Or are you concerned by the potential for a high-volume of files being uploaded? Feel free to edit your question to clarify your concerns.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that the files you are uploading to Amazon S3 are kept as Private and the Amazon S3 bucket is kept as private. These are the default settings and are enforced by [Amazon S3 block public access](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/access-control-block-public-access.html) unless somebody has specifically changed the settings.

With this configuration, the files are only accessible to people with AWS credentials that have been granted permission to access the S3 bucket.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to John's answer you can use AWS KMS (https://aws.amazon.com/kms/?nc1=h_ls) to encrypt your data at rest.

With regards of the file size, you should limit the size of the uploaded file in your application I would say.

Comment: Because the application run on client PC, potentialy user can avoid the file size limitation on client code. I'd like to protect s3 bucket from uploading fake data to consume my money and destroy the analytics.